Mixpanel with static HTML and vanilla javascript
I want to use Mixpanel in a static HTML and vanilla javascript page. All the examples I can find use bower or npm to install mixpanel but these do not exist with a simple HTML and javascript page.
Trying the following:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mixpanel.init('PROJECT TOKEN');

        mixpanel.track("PageView");
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

Gives this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: mixpanel is not defined"
And: "Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide."

The Mixpanel documentation instructs you to insert the following code just before the closing  tag to initalize JS Mixpanel (I didn't include it before closing  tag in the snippet because you want to the script run on page load). Source.
<!-- Paste this right before your closing </head> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function (f, b) { if (!b.__SV) { var e, g, i, h; window.mixpanel = b; b._i = []; b.init = function (e, f, c) { function g(a, d) { var b = d.split("."); 2 == b.length && ((a = a[b[0]]), (d = b[1])); a[d] = function () { a.push([d].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))); }; } var a = b; "undefined" !== typeof c ? (a = b[c] = []) : (c = "mixpanel"); a.people = a.people || []; a.toString = function (a) { var d = "mixpanel"; "mixpanel" !== c && (d += "." + c); a || (d += " (stub)"); return d; }; a.people.toString = function () { return a.toString(1) + ".people (stub)"; }; i = "disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking start_batch_senders people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split( " "); for (h = 0; h < i.length; h++) g(a, i[h]); var j = "set set_once union unset remove delete".split(" "); a.get_group = function () { function b(c) { d[c] = function () { call2_args = arguments; call2 = [c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(call2_args, 0)); a.push([e, call2]); }; } for ( var d = {}, e = ["get_group"].concat( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)), c = 0; c < j.length; c++) b(j[c]); return d; }; b._i.push([e, f, c]); }; b.__SV = 1.2; e = f.createElement("script"); e.type = "text/javascript"; e.async = !0; e.src = "undefined" !== typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL ? MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL : "file:" === f.location.protocol && "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//) ? "https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js" : "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js"; g = f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; g.parentNode.insertBefore(e, g); } })(document, window.mixpanel || []);
</script>

Here is working code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (f, b) { if (!b.__SV) { var e, g, i, h; window.mixpanel = b; b._i = []; b.init = function (e, f, c) { function g(a, d) { var b = d.split("."); 2 == b.length && ((a = a[b[0]]), (d = b[1])); a[d] = function () { a.push([d].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))); }; } var a = b; "undefined" !== typeof c ? (a = b[c] = []) : (c = "mixpanel"); a.people = a.people || []; a.toString = function (a) { var d = "mixpanel"; "mixpanel" !== c && (d += "." + c); a || (d += " (stub)"); return d; }; a.people.toString = function () { return a.toString(1) + ".people (stub)"; }; i = "disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking start_batch_senders people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split( " "); for (h = 0; h < i.length; h++) g(a, i[h]); var j = "set set_once union unset remove delete".split(" "); a.get_group = function () { function b(c) { d[c] = function () { call2_args = arguments; call2 = [c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(call2_args, 0)); a.push([e, call2]); }; } for ( var d = {}, e = ["get_group"].concat( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)), c = 0; c < j.length; c++) b(j[c]); return d; }; b._i.push([e, f, c]); }; b.__SV = 1.2; e = f.createElement("script"); e.type = "text/javascript"; e.async = !0; e.src = "undefined" !== typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL ? MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL : "file:" === f.location.protocol && "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//) ? "https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js" : "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js"; g = f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; g.parentNode.insertBefore(e, g); } })(document, window.mixpanel || []);
    </script>
    <script>
        mixpanel.init('PROJECT TOKEN');

        mixpanel.track("PageView");
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

